# Sound Design SE not listed correctly

Tags: bug, status-norepro, area-51

If one looks at the [Stack Exchange site index list](https://stackexchange.com/sites?view=list&expand=true#oldest), one can observe that the Sound Design site (which is apparently in beta, by the icon), has a site age of 2012 years and 8 months. (The site creation date, as a timestamp, is `-62135596800`.)

[image: "2012y8m site age"]

If you click the link on the index, it goes correctly to [the Sound Design SE](https://sound.stackexchange.com/), but if you click on [the Area 51 link](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/lookup/sound.stackexchange.com), it's not found. A [search of Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/search?q=sound+design&page=1) turns up only unrelated results as well.

I believe this is because it was (just) upgraded to a SE 2.0 site. While it's impressive that this SE predates the Internet, this should probably still be corrected.

Comment: I want to be 2012 years old.

Comment: StackExchange's epoch is 1 A.D? That explains a lot.