# Japanese Stack Overflow is almost as old as Jesus

Tags: bug, stackexchange.com

So, it's [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/195837/192960) again:

[image: 2013y11m]

I feel like this might be a small bit of false advertising on SE's part. It's been like this since the site creation 2-3 days ago.

Comment: -1 because you think Jesus was born before 2 AD. Summer of 4 AD is a more likely match. Also, because this report is a dupe.

Comment: @JanDvorak Oh, so it is. I didn't look for threads that old since, well... kinda figured it would be fixed after 4 days if it had been reported. :P

Comment: @JohnDvorak Duplicate questions can be closed, but being a dupe alone is not a reason to vote to down.